# Android Studio - Java - Intent from Child Activity Not Received in Parent Activity After Back Press

Tags: java, android, android-intent, parent-child

This Intent from my `SetListEditAdapter` class launches my parent class `SetListMasterViewActivity`:

```
    private void openSetListDetails(int setListId) {
        if (openSetListMode == OpenSetListMode.OPEN) {
            Intent openSetListIntent;
            openSetListIntent = new Intent(context, SetListMasterViewActivity.class);
            openSetListIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP); // Add the flag here
            openSetListIntent.putExtra("SET_LIST_ID", setListId);
            context.startActivity(openSetListIntent);
        } else {
            Intent intent;
            intent = new Intent(context, SetListDetailsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("SET_LIST_ID", setListId);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
        Log.d("SttList", "(SetListEditAdapter) line #59 - setListId: " + setListId);
        Log.d("SttList", "(SetListEditAdapter) line #61 - SetListMasterViewActivity launched with setListId: " + setListId);
    }
```

In the newly opened `parent` activity (`SetListMasterViewActivity`) I launch the child activity (`SetListOpenViewActivity`):
Intent openViewIntent = new Intent(SetListMasterViewActivity.this, SetListOpenViewActivity.class);

```
            // Pass necessary data with the intent
            openViewIntent.putExtra("songId", selectedSong.getSongId());
            openViewIntent.putExtra("songName", selectedSong.getSongName());
            openViewIntent.putExtra("setId", setListId); // Assuming you need to pass the setListId
            openViewIntent.putExtra("songsList", new ArrayList<>(songsList)); // Convert List to ArrayList before passing

            // Start the activity
            openViewIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT);
            startActivity(openViewIntent);
```

I receive the Intent in the `child` activity (`SetListOpenViewActivity`) without issue:

```
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        songId = intent.getLongExtra("songId", 0);
        songName = intent.getStringExtra("songName");
        setId = intent.getIntExtra("setId", 0);
        dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        songsList = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("songsList");
```

When the "Back" button in the `child` activity is pressed, processing returns to the `parent` activity with this Intent:

```
                Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
                resultIntent.putExtra("lastViewedSongId", currentSongId);
                resultIntent.putExtra("lastViewedSongName", currentSongName);
                resultIntent.putExtra("backButtonClicked", true); // Include backButtonClicked flag
                setResult(RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
                Log.d("SttList", "(SetListOpenViewActivity) - line #120 - Intent contents: " + getIntent().getExtras());
                Log.d("SttList", "(SetListOpenViewActivity) - line #121 - Setting result intent: " + resultIntent);
                finish();
```

And in the `parent` activity I expect to receive the `child's` Intent here:

```
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d("SttList", "(SetListMasterViewActivity) - line #254 - onResume method start");
        // Check if the Intent contains the backButtonClicked flag
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Log.d("SttList", "(SetListMasterViewActivity) - line #257 - Intent received: " + getIntent().getExtras());
        if (intent != null && intent.hasExtra("backButtonClicked")) {
            boolean backButtonClicked = intent.getBooleanExtra("backButtonClicked", false);
            Log.d("SttList", "(SetListMasterViewActivity) - line #260 - backButtonClicked: " + backButtonClicked);
            if (backButtonClicked) {
                // Handle the back button click
                Log.d("SttList", "(SetListMasterViewActivity) - line #263 - Back button clicked in child activity");

                // Process the backButtonClicked flag here or call onActivityResult if needed
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
```

However the Log.d output is referencing the Intent which is starting the `parent` activity:

```
 D  (SetListMasterViewActivity) - line #257 - Intent received: Bundle[{SET_LIST_ID=280}]
```

**I have tried:**

1. Using `onActivityResult`:

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.d("SttList", "(SetListMasterViewActivity) - line #216 - Received intent: " + data);
        Log.d("SttList", "(SetListMasterViewActivity) line #217 - requestCode: " + requestCode + ", resultCode: " + resultCode);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
...
```

However none of the `Log.d` statements are reached.

2. tried adding this to the `child activity`:

```
    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        setIntent(intent);
    }
```

but again, in the `parent` none of the `child's` `Intents` are received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According docs the method [Activity.getIntent()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getIntent())

> Return the intent that started this activity.

With call `finish()` you are not starting a new activity with intent (like do `startActivity(intent)`. It just destroys the activity and pops up the previous activity from the back stack.

In order to return the result intent from the child activity you need to start it with `startActivityForResult()` and wait data inside `onActivityResult()`. But the modern way changed a little when `Activity Result API` appeared. Start from [guide](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result).

Comment: Thank you @Viewed, this led me to the correct path.  What solved was changing the lines: `openViewIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT); startActivity(openViewIntent);` to this line: `openViewLauncher.launch(openViewIntent);`